# Best strategy for automatize a flow that need user interaction

Tags: linux, bash, shell, docker

I am working in a Dockerfile but there is a "secure" MariaDB server script I need to run which is interactive and I don't know how to deal with this.

Basically this is the flow I have follow on the script at test environment and is the same I want to achieve in the Dockerfile without user interaction by just answering as you seen on the flow below:

```
# /usr/bin/mysql_secure_installation

Enter current password for root (enter for none): [ENTER] // because there is no password
OK, successfully used password, moving on...

Set root password? [Y/n] n
 ... skipping.  

Remove anonymous users? [Y/n] Y
 ... Success!

Disallow root login remotely? [Y/n] n
 ... skipping.

Remove test database and access to it? [Y/n] Y
 - Dropping test database...
 ... Success!
 - Removing privileges on test database...
 ... Success!

Reloading the privilege tables will ensure that all changes made so far
will take effect immediately.

Reload privilege tables now? [Y/n] Y
 ... Success!

Cleaning up...
```

So I need to write a bash script or something else that could handle this automatically but has not idea, how would you take care of this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can try with two different approaches:

1. Use `expect` script eventually "evaluated" from bash. Man page [here](http://www.tcl.tk/man/expect5.31/expect.1.html)

Or:

2. Use "here document" syntax from a bash script (no expect)

** EDIT - Example of option 2 **

```
#!/bin/bash
...
/usr/bin/mysql_secure_installation <<EOF

n
Y
n
Y
Y
EOF
...
```

basically you pass all your answers to the standard input of your mysql_secure_installation.

Using `expect` is just a little bit more complicated. You can start from [here](http://www.admin-magazine.com/Articles/Automating-with-Expect-Scripts)

Comment: Excellent, I get it now just another doubt: if I put this in a script named `secure.sh` will this one call the `/usr/bin/mysql_secure_installation`? I mean I am still not getting how `here document` works since in my mind I should first call the secure_installation script and then answer, could you clear this?

Comment: Now... Yes. There was a typo in my previous version.

Answer (score 1):

Another option, mysql_secure_installation is a simple bash script that executes several mysql commands, just use the sql commands.

```
DELETE FROM mysql.user WHERE User='';
DROP DATABASE test;
DELETE FROM mysql.db WHERE Db='test' OR Db='test\\_%';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

save this commands in a file and pipe it to mysql

```
mysql < my_file.sql
```